# Docker Postgresql can't connect remotely

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, docker

I can connect my docker postgresql in my local server windows via ip or localhost. When I try to connect it remotely from my personal windows I have timeout error. Thinking about 5432 port is blocked or not listening.
[image: docker-compose.yml]
[image: Dockerfile]

I have changed pg_hba.conf & postgresql.conf files for remote connection and also checked for firewall but it was disabled.

[image: postgresql.conf]

[image: pg_hba.conf]

[image: ufw_status]

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  How are you connecting to the database?  How did you start it?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], with the required details as text and not images?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is I should have checked my server's firewall conf also, just dockerVM is not enough :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).